# How to change a certain part of web address with JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I wanted to set automatic links with  tags and I wonder how to make it happen so I don't have to write every case for the site.

I have Polish and English versions of the same site, but I have a problem with the web address.
For example I have sites like this:
https://example.com/tech/privacy-policy - Polish one
and
https://example.com/tech/en/privacy-policy - English one

How to make it to separate the web address into string and if it is on the Polish site to embed "en" between tech/.../privacy-policy, and how to delete it when I'm on English one?
I know that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; shows me web address in PHP but I don't know how manipulate it in this certain way.

Is it possible to search for "/tech/" for futher web adresses like https:/example.com/tech/en/privacy-policy/something to search for this word and delete "en" if it's English site redirecting to Polish one and add one if it's the opposite side?

Comment: You tagged this `wordpress`, so you probably have some sort of multi-language setup in there already? Then you should use the methods this implementation already offers, instead of trying to manipulate URLs on your own somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "search"? Where exactly do these links need to be changed?

Comment: Which web server are you using? And, do you have access to its config? You should be able to accomplish what you want through server config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` method of Javascript:

```
function changeSiteLanguage() {
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.includes("/tech/en/")) {
        url = url.replace("/tech/en/", "/tech/")
    } else if (url.includes("/tech/")) {
        url = url.replace("/tech/", "/tech/en/")
    }

    // reload window with new URL 
    window.location.assign(url)
}
```

**Test Cases:**

```js
var url1 = "https://example.com/tech/en/privacy-policy";

if (url1.includes("/tech/en/")) {
    url1 = url1.replace("/tech/en/", "/tech/")
} else if (url1.includes("/tech/")) {
    url1 = url1.replace("/tech/", "/tech/en/")
}

console.log(url1)

var url2 = "https://example.com/tech/privacy-policy";

if (url2.includes("/tech/en/")) {
    url2 = url2.replace("/tech/en/", "/tech/")
} else if (url2.includes("/tech/")) {
    url2 = url2.replace("/tech/", "/tech/en/")
}

console.log(url2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using javascript:

```js
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = 'https://example.com/tech/en/privacy-policy';
var pathArray = url.pathname.split("/");
var newPathPolish = "";
var newPathEnglish = "";

function checkPath(urlPath) {
 return urlPath === "tech";
}

//Add en in the path if it doesn't exist
if (!pathArray.includes("en")) {
 indexAfter = pathArray.findIndex(checkPath) + 1;
 pathArray.splice(indexAfter, 0, "en");
}

//Loop through the path creating the new paths
for (var i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i = i + 1)
{
 if (pathArray[i] !== "en") {
   newPathPolish += pathArray[i] + '/';
 } 
 newPathEnglish += pathArray[i] + '/';
}
console.log("Polish version: " + url.origin + newPathPolish);
console.log("English version: " + url.origin + newPathEnglish);
```